# how to loop a vector comparing rows without FOR

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I need some hints to make effective loop in vector but for “FOR…” loop because of optimization issues.
At first glance, it is recommended to use such functions as `apply()`, `sapply()`.

I have a vector converted into matrix:

```
x1<-c(1,2,4,1,4,3,5,3,1,0)
```

Looping through the vector I need to replace all x1[i+1]=x1[i] if x[i]>x[i+1].
Example:
Input vector:

```
x1<-as.matrix(c(1,2,4,1,4,3,5,3,1,0))
```

Output vector:

```
c(1,2,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
```

My approach is to use user function in `apply()` but I have some difficulties how to code correctly the relation of x[i] and x[i+1] in user function.
I would be very grateful for your ideas or hints.

Comment: @Khashaa Please consider to post that as a solution.  It is an excellent option.

Comment: @akrun Too short for a proper answer. You might as well add it to your answer.

Comment: @Khashaa I am not going to steal your excellent answer :-).  Also, if the answer is compact and short, it is not your fault

Comment: I'll tack it onto a general answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can use `Reduce` with `accumulate=TRUE` for cumulative operations

```
Reduce(max,x1,accumulate=TRUE)
# [1] 1 2 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

But as @Khashaa points out, the common cases `cumsum`,`cumprod`,`cummin`, and yours, `cummax` are provided as efficient base functions.

```
cummax(x1)
# [1] 1 2 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks A. Webb. cummax(x1) is really great. the best result of all options - elapsed time is 0,02 sec on vector of 1mio items :-)

Answer (score 2):

We could do this using `ave`. (Using the `vector` x1)

```
 ave(x1,cumsum(c(TRUE,x1[-1]>x1[-length(x1)])), FUN=function(x) head(x,1))
 #[1] 1 2 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

We create a grouping variable based on the condition described in the OP's post.  Check whether the succeeding element (`x1[-1]` - removed first element) is greater than the current element (`x1[-length(x1)]` -removed last element).

```
 x1[-1]>x1[-length(x1)]
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The length is one less than the length of the vector x1.  So, we append `TRUE` to make the length equal and then do the `cumsum`

```
 cumsum(c(TRUE,x1[-1]>x1[-length(x1)]))
 #[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

This we use as grouping variable in `ave` and select the first observation of  'x1' 
within each group

---

Another option would to get the logical index (`c(TRUE, x1[-1] > x1[-length(x1)])`) as before, negate it (`!`) so that TRUE becomes FALSE, and FALSE as TRUE, convert the TRUE values to 'NA' (`NA^(!...)`), and then use `na.locf` from `library(zoo)` to replace the `NA` values with the preceding non-NA value.

```
 library(zoo)
 na.locf(x1*NA^(!c(TRUE,x1[-1]>x1[-length(x1)])))
 #[1] 1 2 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Your hints are really great!

Comment: @DimonD. Glad to know that it helped.  Thanks for the feedback.